Is there a way to extract text from python datacompy comparison result?
I am using datacompy to compare all columns from two dataframe. My goal is to extract the column(s) name with unmatched values.
In the below example, I used inventory_id as a join column to compare df1 and df2. One column shows unmatched value, which is 'indinv_vari_ware_uid'. This is a simple example, in real work situation, it's common to see more than one column with unmatched values.
Is there a way to programmatically extract these unmatched column name from the result? The end goal is to print these column names in a text file or in the log instead of having users to read the compare report (there will be hundreds of them in each production run).
import datacompy
compare = datacompy.Compare(df1, df2, join_columns=['inventory_id'], 
df1_name='df1', df2_name='df2')  
print(compare.report())



You can use compare.column_stats for this: a list with dictionaries that contain the relevant information per column.

Sample setup:

import pandas as pd
import datacompy

data = {'id': [1, 2],
        'col1': [1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'id': [1, 2],
         'col1': ['A', 'B']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

compare = datacompy.Compare(df1, df2, join_columns=['id'])


Print:

print(compare.report())

# ...

Columns with Unequal Values or Types
------------------------------------

  Column df1 dtype df2 dtype  # Unequal  Max Diff  # Null Diff
0   col1     int64    object          2       0.0            0

Sample Rows with Unequal Values
-------------------------------

   id  col1 (df1) col1 (df2)
0   2           2          B
1   1           1          A


Access column_stats:

compare.column_stats

[{'column': 'id',
  'match_column': '',
  'match_cnt': 2,
  'unequal_cnt': 0,
  'dtype1': 'int64',
  'dtype2': 'int64',
  'all_match': True,
  'max_diff': 0.0,
  'null_diff': 0},
 {'column': 'col1',
  'match_column': 'col1_match',
  'match_cnt': 0,
  'unequal_cnt': 2,
  'dtype1': 'int64',
  'dtype2': 'object',
  'all_match': False,
  'max_diff': 0.0,
  'null_diff': 0}]


Use a list comprehension to get all column names where unequal_cnt != 0:

unmatched_columns = [stat['column'] for stat in compare.column_stats
                     if stat['unequal_cnt'] != 0]
unmatched_columns
# ['col1']

It might also be convenient to create a df with pd.DataFrame, and filter as desired:
column_stats = pd.DataFrame(compare.column_stats)

column_stats

  column match_column  match_cnt  unequal_cnt dtype1  dtype2  all_match  \
0     id                       2            0  int64   int64       True   
1   col1   col1_match          0            2  int64  object      False   

   max_diff  null_diff  
0       0.0          0  
1       0.0          0

# e.g. column_stats[column_stats['unequal_cnt'].ne(0)]  


Thanks for this solution. I never thought about utlizing compare.column_stats to identify columns with unmatched values. This works like a charm. Really apperciated for your detail explanation and solution.

You're welcome. Good luck with the project!
